# Python netmiko: How to print out specific line matches with 'Cisco IOS Software' in the 'show version' command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco, netmiko

This is sample output of Cisco Switch show version command.

```
Switch#show version
Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
```

Objective: If string `Cisco IOS Software` is found in the 'show version' output, I would like to print the whole line.

To make it easier to understand, let me put `show version` output in variable `shvar`

```
shvar = '''
Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
'''
```

Search with `if`

```
>>> if 'Cisco IOS Software' in shvar:
...     print('Found ... print line')
... 
Found ... print line
>>>
```

Or Search with `find`

```
>>> if shvar.find('Cisco IOS Software') > 0:
...     print('Found ... print line')
... 
Found ... print line
>>>
```

The question is how do I print the line matches with 'Cisco IOS Software'?

Desired Output

```
Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just split the string into lines.

```
for line in shvar.split("\n"):
   if 'Cisco IOS Software' in line:
      print(line)
```